# Line-by-line Remote Data Transmission in Python

Tags: python, linux, process, ssh, ipc

I've been playing with the `subprocess` module to iteratively send
each line in an input file to a process created by the following command.

```
ssh -t -A $host 'remote_command'
```

The `remote_command` expects a line in its STDIN, does some processing on the
line and iterates the cycle until STDIN closes or reaches EOF.

To achieve this, what I'd been doing was:

```
process = subprocess.Popen("ssh -t -A $host 'remote_command'",
                           shell=True,
                           stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in file('/tmp/foo'):
  process.stdin.write(line)
  process.stdin.flush()
process.stdin.close()
```

But what I discovered was that the above method is not robust enough, as it is
often the case that `remote_command` finishes prematurely without processing the
entire content (though sometimes the same code does succeed without a problem).

The situation is the same when I employ another, albeit very simiar, approach:

```
process = subprocess.Popen("ssh -t -A $host 'remote_command'",
                           shell=True,
                           stdin=file('/tmp/foo'))
```

So the question is: **How can I make sure that each line in an input file be sent, received, and processed until the end by the remote machine in Python?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this...

```
process = subprocess.Popen("ssh -t -A $host 'remote_command'",
                           shell=True,
                           stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in file('/tmp/foo'):
    process.stdin.write(line)
    process.stdin.flush()
process.stdin.close()
```

...is your entire program, it won't (necessarily) work.

Although the final call to `process.stdin.close()` will ensure that all the data has been sent to the `ssh` process before your program terminates, it won't ensure that the `ssh` process has sent all the data across the network, so there may well be some outstanding data for it to send.

Unfortunately, since the `ssh` process is a child process of your program, then when your program terminates, the `ssh` process will receive a `SIGHUP` which will immediately kill it, potentially before it finishes sending all its data.

As long as the `remote_command` terminates when it hits EOF, it's not a problem, and you can either ask the `ssh` process to ignore the `SIGHUP`, and continue running in the background with...

```
process = subprocess.Popen("nohup ssh -t -A $host 'remote_command'", ...)
```

...or ask your program to wait for the `ssh` process to finish, by adding...

```
process.wait()
```

...to the end of your program.

---

**Update**

Upon further examination, it looks like a process only gets a `SIGHUP` if its controlling tty terminates, not its parent process.

It may be something to do with the `-t` option which creates a new controlling tty on the remote host, and that's exiting before the subprocess it spawns has finished.

In which case, you might need...

```
process = subprocess.Popen("ssh -t -A $host 'nohup remote_command'", ...)
```

...or try it without the `-t` option.

Comment: Thanks, yet again, for the idea I haven't seen anywhere else. Will try `nohup` and get back to you.

Comment: @OTZ See updated answer. Might help to explain what `remote_command` is, so I can attempt to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do much more than what you have done to make sure that all input gets **sent** to your child process. Your second example is better than the first one, in my opinion. What you can do is inspecting the return code from your child process.

```
return_code = p.wait()
```

Your remote command should probably return 0 on successful completion and something non zero if an error occurred.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of wrapping around a subprocess, you'd likely be better off using something like [paramiko](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/).

But in either case, if your connection gets terminated before you've sent all your data, you can catch that exception and you'll know that you need to retry. In the event the process dies prematurely you should be able to read the exit-code of the process.

Comment: What would be the advantages of using paramiko over subprocess in this case?

Comment: The advantage of using paramiko is that you'd have more visibility to the reason the connection failed since you'd get an exception from the communication stream rather than a simple 1 or 0 error code from the ssh binary through subprocess.

Answer (score 0):

I would say your best bet would be to use the reply pipe to capture the results of the remote command and ensure that you reach a prompt between lines and after each line.  BTW I have sometimes found that a dummy command such as ls -l at the end of a remote link session helps to ensure that processing is finished before dropping the connection.